# Magento - Customer default address always taken instead of customer chosen address in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

I noticed that Magento saves the default address after placing an order from checkout page, even when customer choose other addresses rather than the default.

In other words, all orders have the default address as billing and shipping address (if customer have default address).

Is it a bug in Magento or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Are you using a custom extension for your checkout?

Comment: @JonathanRibas Yes, I use ShopGo, but I disabled it and still having issue with address.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme also?

Comment: Yes, may it cause this ??

Comment: Try RWD theme to be sure it's not a core Magento issue. I'm pretty sure it's not but give it a try.